# Why are the leaves of my Japanese Sweet Potato gradually turning yellow?

Tags: diseases, root-vegetables

The leaves of my Japanese Sweet Potato plant (satsumaimo, サツマイモ) are gradually turning yellow, from the bottom to the top of the plant and from outside in on each leaf. The first picture shows the process in its early stage, the second picture shows the underside of the yellowing area of the same leaf.

What is happening here and how can I stop it`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a shot of the whole plant.